River City Ransom clone for the Windows PC that included zombies, toxic vomit, and the ability to tear an opponent's heart from their chest
I think I played this in the early 2000s, although the memory isn't firm. It used the large cartoony graphics like River City Ranson, including oversized heads. And, as with that game, you could buy new moves for your character. In this case, I firmly remember one of the moves you could buy involving punching your hand into an opponent's chest and ripping out their heart, killing them instantly. I think that you might have also gotten a small health boost for using the move because you took a bite out of the heart. I think there was also a move where you could vomit toxic blood to hurt an opponent, which you only got after successfully beating the zombie enemy.
I also remember the game having a New Game Plus that I got to, one of the reasons I was able to use those special abilities through most of the game, because I started it from the beginning with most abilities unlocked.
I'm pretty sure it's not Charlie Murder despite that being a beat-em-up that TV Tropes mentions both allowing you to rip the heart out, but also get health from eating it (if you have another ability). I watched some gameplay, and it doesn't look right.
